# How can I create a websocket with PHP and Ratchet?

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, ratchet

I have been trying to create a Ratchet web socket with PHP for quite a while without success. I have referenced documentation on the Github page and the Ratchet website. Does anyone know of better documentation or, if you have experience, could you explain how I create a basic web socket? Thank you.

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 16.04 with a working, online, live Apache web server with PHP. This is what I've tried:

- Installed Ratchet with composer
- Created an html page and the PHP web socket server page in the /var/www/html/webSocket/

This is what `chat-server-socket-test.php` looks like:

```
<?php
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

    // Make sure composer dependencies have been installed
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * chat.php
 * Send any incoming messages to all connected clients (except sender)
 */
class MyChat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from != $client) {
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        $conn->close();
    }
}

    // Run the server application through the WebSocket protocol on port 8080
    $app = new Ratchet\App('localhost', 8080);
    $app->route('/chat', new MyChat);
    $app->route('/echo', new Ratchet\Server\EchoServer, array('*'));
    $app->run();
?>
```

This is what my HTML page looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
// Then some JavaScript in the browser:
    var conn = new WebSocket('ws://williamgreen.hopto.org/webSocket/chat-server-socket-test.php:8080/echo');
    conn.onmessage = function(e) { console.log(e.data); };
    conn.send('Hello Me!');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>web socket</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error I receive in the web browser's console:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still
>   in CONNECTING state.
>       at http://williamgreen.hopto.org/webSocket/test.html:8:10
>
> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://williamgreen.hopto.org/webSocket/chat-server-socket-test.php:8080/echo'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   404

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood a few things. You need to execute the script from the server side (eg. `php chat-server-socket-test.php`) then your websocket address will be (probably) `ws://williamgreen.hopto.org:8080/echo`. Remember that your port goes on the end of the domain name, not any other part of the URL.

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Comment: I was able to fix the errors with your tips and by enabling PHP error reporting.

Comment: Now, I have this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught React\Socket\ConnectionException: Could not bind to tcp://127.0.0.1:80: Permission denied in /var/www/html/webSocket/vendor/react/socket/src/Server.php:90 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/webSocket/vendor/cboden/ratchet/src/Ratchet/App.php(80): React\Socket\Server->listen(80, '127.0.0.1') #1 /var/www/html/webSocket/chat-server-socket-test.php(46): Ratchet\App->__construct('localhost', 80) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/webSocket/vendor/react/socket/src/Server.php on line 90`. Could you help me understand the problem?

Comment: It appears the user that is running PHP does not have permission to open sockets in your OS.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll conduct further research. Do you know how I can enable access?